# How can decode the password using BCryptPasswordEncoder?

Tags: encryption, spring-security, decode, bcrypt

I want to decode the encrypted value from database. I want to sent the actual password to user via mail when he gave forgot password.

The following is the code used for encoding the passowrd

```
BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
String password = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
```

How can do the decode?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

BCrypt is a password hashing function, i.e. a [one-way function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function).

You can't decrypt a BCrypt hash just like you can't go back from chicken mcnuggets to the original chicken.

You can only verify that two BCrypt hashes are the same, thus verifying that a supplied password matches the original one.

A typical solution to this is to send a single-use password reset link to the user, use secret questions or some other information confirming user identity to let them set a new password.

Comment: Pretty simple and clear explain

Answer (score 1):

It is not advisable to send the actual password to the user. you can send an activation link rather in an email.